# Delphi: Disable undo in Memo/Edit

Tags: delphi, winapi, vcl, delphi-xe6

I have implemented an UndoManager for a `TMemo`/`TEdit` and now I want to disable default Undo behavior (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and Undo in context menu) is these components and instead do my undo/redo commands.

I tried to catch `WM_UNDO`, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> seems sending another message. Also I don't know how to handle it after message received (for example for `WM_PASTE` we could clear clipboard)

Comment: Have you tried clearing the undo buffer with Memo1.Perform(EM_EMPTYUNDOBUFFER, 0, 0);

Comment: This works, but needs to be send whenever new changes is applied (may be use this in OnChnage event).

Comment: `TEdit` and `TMemo` have a `ClearUndo()` method, and a `CanUndo` property.

Comment: @RemyLebeau is there any solution rather than "checking for `CanUndo` and then `ClearUndo`" (something like turn it off in the first place)?

Comment: @SAMPro Nevermind, I forgot what `CanUndo` was really meant for. In which case, no, there is no other solution. But, what you could do is perform that check inside of a `TApplication(Events).OnIdle` or `TAction.OnUpdate` event handler, so it gets performed automatically whenever the app enters an idle state after processing messages. No need to track any UI changes manually, eg: `procedure TMyForm.ApplicationIdle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean); begin if Edit1.CanUndo then Edit1.ClearUndo; end;`